# How to list the employees who are senior to most recently hired employee working under a particular manager in the below schema?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a schema of emp table defined as emp ( empno ,ename ,job ,mgr ,hiredate) and I have to evaluate the query for the problem statement :

List the employees who are senior to most recently hired employee working under king.

I wrote the query as :

```
select hiredate from emp where hiredate < ANY 
( select e.hiredate from emp e where e.mgr= (select e.empno from emp e 
where e.ename='KING') order by hiredate desc )
```

This query is giving syntax error ,please help me out .

Comment: Why the ORDER BY in the sub-query? Don't use same table alias several times in a query.

Comment: Order by used is to get the most recently hired employee whose manager is kING

Comment: Tag RDBMS which you are using?

Comment: But you still select all rows. That ORDER BY makes no difference at all.

Comment: I have edited my query as  :                                                                  select hiredate from emp where hiredate < (select max(hiredate) from emp e where e.mgr=(select e.empno from emp e where e.ename='KING')) ,It is working fine but then why is my query mentioned above in the question

Comment: `< ANY` should be `< ALL`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think that even with `ALL` the query would fail with the `ORDER BY` clause in a subquery. And it wouldn't make sense with the desired output (filter on **most recently** hired employee working under KING).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max function instead-

```
select hiredate 
from emp 
where hiredate < ( select max(hiredate) 
                   from emp 
                   where mgr= (select e.empno 
                               from emp e 
                                where e.ename='KING'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get employees working under `King` who joined in the last 7 days, you can try:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM emp e
WHERE e.mgr = (SELECT empno FROM emp WHERE ename='KING') AND
      e.hiredate > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Note that the subquery to find King's employee number is not correlated.  So this is the friendly sort of subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use a max to find the greatest hire date, and a join instead of the subquery.

```
select * from emp where hiredate < 
  (select max(e.hiredate) 
   from emp e 
   join emp mg on e.mgr = mg.empno
   where mg.ename = 'KING')
```

I guess you have this error message

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

So you should add a `TOP 1`  to have it work (but well, is this really more readable ?)

```
select hiredate from emp where hiredate < ANY 
(select TOP 1 e.hiredate from emp e where e.mgr= (select e.empno from emp e 
where e.ename='KING') order by hiredate desc )
```

Comment: I agree to your solution but why is above query not working ,I have used ANY clause , why is not working >

Comment: @stackuser Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   emp
WHERE  hiredate < ANY (SELECT hiredate
                       FROM   emp
                       WHERE  ename = 'MILLER');
```

Comment: U CAN USE THIS CODE FOR FINDING SR MEMBER OF A PARTICULAR PERSON.

Comment: Please use [edit] to add information to your post instead of comments. Also avoid all caps. Its shouting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.